# How can I access stdout.columns in Node on Windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, cmd, terminal

I am writing some node code to stick a bit of text on the far right of the console. My code works great, but whenever I call process.stdout.columns it says that my window is 80 wide, no matter what the actual width is. I am running cmd.exe on windows 7 x64. Is the use of process.stdout.columns still supported?

Comment: How are you changing the width of the terminal?

Comment: It works on Linux, so that must be a platform-specific problem. If you modify the properties of the command window (right-click on the top-left window icon), and modify the window size there, does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Felix is almost right. In Windows the property for the tty process.stdout.columns is decided by `Screen Buffer Size` from Command Prompt Window Properties. The actual width is decided by `Window Size`. Both are different in windows but for linux it is the same.

Unfortunately you cannot change Buffer Size/column width with resizing in Windows.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Changing the max window size in the properties worked, but resizing the window did not. Is anything I can do to figure out how wide the console acutally is in windows?

Comment: I tried process.stdout.getWindowSize(), but it still returned the max width of the console, but the correct height for some reason.

Comment: I, too, am looking for a solution to this. There's *got* to be a way to access `Window Size` instead of `Screen Buffer Size` from within Node. Perhaps a native extension that could be packaged as a module?